# Fetch API - Content-Type is sent as text/plain when it's set to application/json

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

In my React app when I submit a form to create a new user I create a request to the server using `fetch`.

The code is this one:

```
fetch('http://0.0.0.0:3000/users', {
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'no-cors',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
}).then(response => console.log(response))
```

When I check the entry in the Network tab under the Developer Tools I see that the Content-Type is `text/plain` but I do not understand why if I set it as `application/json`.

I have tried using the option `Edit and send` in the request and replace `text/plain` to `application/json` but after sending it it is sent as `text/plain`.

Comment: If you've set `no-cors` because you were getting _"No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present..."_ errors, that is not a solution

Answer (score 13):

The mode:"no-cors" option is the culprit.

Remove that option and it should work

To fix it pass a new headers object

```
headers: new Headers({'content-type': 'application/json'})
```

Comment: I still get the same result

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: The `headers` option also accepts a plain object. It does not _need_ to be an instance of `Headers`

Comment: no-cors solved my problem. thanks..

Comment: for me "cors" mode helped as I had API on other domain